# Combine --scale and --no-deps in 'docker-compose up'

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I didn't manage to find out how to use the scale parameter (which allow to run multiple instance of the docker container) without launching the dependencies in the docker-compose file.

Assuming "Worker" depends of "App"
When I do `docker-compose up --no-deps --scale worker=2`, App will be launched too...

Thanks for helping.

Comment: Adding the service name to the `up` command works for me. `docker-compose up --no-deps worker --scale worker=2`

Answer (score 0):

The workaround is :

```
docker-compose up --no-start worker
docker-compose scale worker=2
docker-composer logs -f worker
```

This provide the expected behavior.